# How to make sure setter is done before using getter in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Whenever I call my getter I am being returned an undefined value. I have a setter in one of my services, and I am wanting to set a variable then when I use a getter function I want return that variable. I believe the problem is that my setter is running asynchronously so it is not setting my variable before I need to use the getter. I am confused on how to make sure my setter is done before I do anything else. I feel like I need to use a promise but am confused on how to do so. Maybe I am just doing this wrong all together.

```js
// team-member.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const TEAM_API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/team';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TeamMemberService {
  memberPermissions: any; // Variable that is returned as undefined.

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.setTeamMemberPermissions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt')).user['username'];
    console.log(this.getTeamMemberPermissions); // Only logging for testing purposes. Getter will be used in my components
  } 

  public singleTeamMemberInfo(username: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(TEAM_API_URL + '/user/list/' + username);
  }

  set setTeamMemberPermissions(username: string) {
    this.singleTeamMemberInfo(username).pipe(map((r => {
      this.memberPermissions = r['results'][0].permission;
    }))));
  }

  get getTeamMemberPermissions() {
    return this.memberPermissions;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't subscribe to the `singleTeamMemberInfo` observable, so the http request is not made and the code from pipe is never called. You should replace the `pipe(map..)` with `subscribe`

If you want to check if the value was correctly set, remove the `console.log` from constructor and move it to `setTeamMemberPermissions` setter

Try this code

```
set setTeamMemberPermissions(username: string) {
  this.singleTeamMemberInfo(username).subscribe(
    r => {
       this.memberPermissions = r['results'][0].permission
       console.log(this.getTeamMemberPermissions)
  });
}
```

#### Edit

If you want to wait till the `memberPermission` is set you should store the memberPermission in a BehaviorSubject

```
// team-member.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const TEAM_API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/team';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TeamMemberService {

  // Store the member permission in BehaviorSubject
  private memberPermissions = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null); // Variable that is returned as undefined.

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.setTeamMemberPermissions();
  }

  public singleTeamMemberInfo(username: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(TEAM_API_URL + '/user/list/' + username);
  }

  private setTeamMemberPermissions() {
    const username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt')).user['username'];
    this.singleTeamMemberInfo(username).subscribe(
      r => {
        const permissions = r['results'][0].permission;
        this.memberPermissions.next(permissions)
      }
    )
  }

  get teamMemberPermissions$(): Observable<any> {
    return this.memberPermissions.asObservable();
  }
}


// In your component
export class TeamMemberComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private teamMemberService: TeamMemberService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.teamMemberService.teamMemberPermissions$
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value))
  }
}
```

Comment: Even when I subscribe it still is undefined in my components. If I console.log from inside the setter I receive the correct result, but I assume that is because the assignment finishes before the console.log is run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to control how the async code works together, setter and getter is not sufficient in this case, you can try `BehaviorSubject()`

```
//set up with an initial false value
memberPermissions=new BehaviorSubject(null)

//it'll only emit when there is a truthy value
getMemberPermission=memberPermisssion.pipe(fliter(value=>!!value))

// when you get your permission from http call 
// you just call .next()
this.http.get<any>(TEAM_API_URL + '/user/list/' + username)
.subscribe(p=>memberPermissions.next(p));
```